# LuaLaTeX + fontspec: cannot compare documents with Acrobat

Tags: luatex, fontspec, acrobat, comparison

I use the option "compare documents" in Adobe Acrobat Pro a lot to highlight changes between revisions. What I just noticed is, if I compile a simple document such as the one below with LuaLaTeX + fontspec, Acrobat is unable to perform the comparison, giving a unspecific error message ("cannot compare document..."). Compiling the same document without fontspec allows the comparison, as does XeLaTeX + fontspec.

I tried with TeX Live 2012 and the current MikTeX, without success. So the issue is some interaction of LuaLaTeX and fontspec. Does anyone know what is going on and of a possible fix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your document uses libertineotf which does a lot more than simply load fontspec. Try at first if the problem is also only with fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did that of course, the result is identical (I just used `libertineotf` for simplicity of the MWE). Edit: little change in the MWE.

Comment: libertineotf complicates the example as it changes the font setup. Try what happens if you use `\usepackage{luaotfload}
\font\test=Arial
\pagestyle{empty}` and `\test` after `\begin{document}` instead of fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tried `luaotfload` without `fontspec`, same error.

Comment: So it looks like a problem with the font loader and/or the binary. I don't have Adobe pro currently (this can change in the next days) so I can't make tests myself. I think it would be a good idea to post your problem to the luatex-user mailing list and perhaps also to the context mailing list (luaotfload is base on the font loader from context.)

Comment: Try [diffpdf](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) instead.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Using a different system is not really a solution. DiffPDF is not bad, but Acrobat's functionality is much better, especially as I send the document to other users who make comments on it using Acrobat again.

Comment: Try the following.
(1) Open Adobe Distiller 

(2) Set Default Settings to Standard
OR
(2a) Set Default Settings to PDF/A-1b:2005 (CMYK)
(2b) Select settings > Edit Adobe PDF settings
(2c) Select Compatibility as Acrobat 4.0 (PDF 1.3)
(2d) Select OK
(2e) Save as PDFA1b 2005 CMYK(1).joboptions (or somename.joboptions)
(2f) Set Default Settings to PDFA1b 2005 CMYK(1).joboptions (or somename.joboptions)

(3) Open Acrobat
(4) Select Document > Compare Documents
(5) Choose two files to compare
(6) Select Document Description as Scanned documents
(7) Click OK

Comment: @Sony That does work of sorts, but is quite useless as it handles the text as graphic, hence you cannot see how the text has changed.

Comment: @Jörg: Most people seem to think it is a bug in Acrobat Pro.  I  ran another test by comparing two files created by LuaLaTeX.  One file has the sentence `This is a test.` and the other has the sentence `this is another test`.  Then I compared the two files choosing `scanned documents`(document description) option.  It treats text as images but it found the difference between the images.

Comment: just stumbled across this one, and thought I'd add that your example compares without problems in my version of Acrobat, which is 7.1.0. What version of Acrobat Pro are you using?

Comment: @NilsL Adobe changed the document comparison completely from v9 onwards. It works with all versions below 9 (but the new system is much improved).

Comment: Is this issue possibly related to the one I describe here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102861/is-lualatex-producing-faulty-pdfs ?

Comment: @Christoph Could very well be the case.

Comment: @Jörg: was this question solved? If so, please supply an answer (make it Community Wiki, if it's not your merit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TexLive 2013 and Adobe Acrobat XI the issue appears to be resolved.