# Adobe Garamond and LaTeX (Linux)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, linux, opentype, arxiv

I'm currently writing a math-heavy Ph.D. thesis (more about this in a minute) and, as I truly love **Adobe Garamond**, I would like to use it. However, given its cost, I would like to **make sure that I make the right choice of format, and that I will be able to use it without problem** in my documents. Note that focusing on this particular font makes sense to me, as it is one of the most discussed font around.

Many people ask questions about using fonts in LaTeX, and I've spend many hours (really) **searching for a bulletproof and up-to-date method** to use them. For the record, note that I am working under Debian and I'm not at all used to handling fonts.

**Constraint.**
You see, there is a constraint: as *I'm using arxiv.org*, I'm somehow stuck with LaTeX (pdfLaTeX). Many "easy solutions" I have found involve switching to XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or ConTeXt. However, *I simply cannot switch permanently for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX* (but I can however use them, if it's not too involved, for CV and letters), ConTeXt being even less suitable.

**Uses.**
Now, I'm thinking of two different uses for the font:

- in CV, letters and such;
- in my Ph.D. thesis, which I would like to upload on arxiv.org once finished.

**Format.**
Given the circumstances, should I go for:

- OpenType

or

- Type1?

OpenType is totally fine for XeLateX, from what I understand, thanks to fontspec. On the other hand, Type1 is what LaTeX natively uses (but I do not know how to handle it). Also, are Type1 fonts extracted somehow from OpenType as good as native Type1 fonts or is there a quality loss?

**Installation & use.**
Depending on the answer(s) to the previous question:

- how to install the font (either as it is or via a conversion)

and

- how to use it in LaTeX in a minimal example?

Most threads in SX typically only focus on very specific parts of the process, and it's extremely confusing. Usually, I would just go for trials and errors but as I have to purchase first, it doesn't seem to be the best option.

**What about maths?**
How should one deal with mathematical expressions? Possibly: which alternative fonts should one use?

**Humble request.**
I could not find an *A-to-Z method to install fonts and use them in LaTeX for a Linux distribution*, but I've seen many topics in SX where people display a great knowledge of those things. I truly believe that, if one such person would accept to make a *comprehensive and detailed walkthrough*, *it might be one of the most useful post around*. I'd be more than happy to offer as much of my current reputation as I can to such a person. But tell me what you think about that.

**I thank you very much for your time.**

---

Edit: I am well aware that arxiv.org does not accept proprietary fonts, but not putting my thesis there is not an option. I'll just revert back to the default font when I upload it there.
Edit: Apparently OpenType should be the way to go, even though they are harder to use in pdflatex.

Comment: This could be of interest for anyone using both arxiv.org and Linux (note that Adobe only offers support for Windows and Mac).

Comment: I would go for open type and convert the fonts with the lcdf tools to type1 for pdflatex (naturally the licence should allow the conversion). Regarding a comprehensive guide: I suggest for a start the fontinstallationguide (100 pages).

Comment: Addition: If you go for open type you should make sure that you get the PostScript-flavoured version (otf).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So, if I understand well, (if I can indeed convert) I need what they refer to as OpenType CFF fonts in their user guide.

Comment: Yes, the lcdf tools can only handle this type of open type fonts. But before you buy you should try out if you can handle the conversion. The autoinst-script can help you.

Comment: Can you upload the fonts on arxiv? As far as I know, only default fonts can be used. Furthermore, if you need math, the conversion and setup will be much more involved! Your best bet might be the adaptation of [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) to Garamond (unfortunately, I don't have the time to assist much).

Comment: There is a page where they say that proprietary fonts are not supported by arxiv: http://arxiv.org/help/faq/freefonts

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Yes, I'm aware that arxiv does not support proprietary fonts (I've seen it discussed somewhere in SX) but, still, I would like to put my thesis there once it's finished; I'll just revert back to the default font.
Based on this, I have a naive question: is the backward compatibility between LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX sufficient so that I could just change the main file (where I include packages, set memoir options, load fonts and \include the different chapters) to switch back to LaTeX without actually changing anything in the chapter files themselves?

Comment: As for the math fonts; aren't there non-proprietary math fonts that would fit nicely with Garamond? As I said, I do not have much experience with all this myself (just experimenting with what I've found here and there).

Comment: @Alex Why don't you start with lmodern, which should cover all your needs and postpone the experiments with Garamond until you finished the thesis?

Comment: I regularly use the Palatino + Euler combination.  This has the benefit of working smoothly on the arXiv, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3779

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but... I also love Garamond but after using "Charter", I've fallen in love with it. Do try out including `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` to see if you like the output.

Comment: Thank you for those font suggestions; I'll make sure to try them all. About postponing the experiments with Garamond, I will actually have some time once the thesis is completed, and before it's printed. I am just gathering in advance as much information as possible.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/ containing the EB Garamond font? It has the benefit of both being Garamond and open. Might be something you can use and be able to upload without switching font...

Comment: @Alex What do you think of [Arno Pro](http://www.adobe.com/de/type/browser/landing/arno/arno.html)? It features opticals and greek letters in contrast to Garamond Pro. Especially due to the latter, good math support shouldn't be too difficult with [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro). I might find the time to look at in during the next 2 weeks.

Comment: Would you by any chance have access to a Mac to write (or at least compile) your thesis? The reason I ask is that Adobe's `Garamond Premier Pro` is installed by default under MacOSX, and hence can be used directly if you run MacTeX2012 -- I assume MacTeX2011 will work too -- with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. For a compatible "oldstyle" or "garalde" math font, I suggest you look into the "Asana Math" font; it meshes very well with the `Palatino` text font and should thus also harmonize nicely with a `Garamond` font. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30066/5001 on the topic of math fonts.

Comment: @Alex, you ask about compatibility issues between `pdftex` and `XeTeX` (etc.). To clear any confusion: These are different TeX _engines_; if you only use TeX's built-in fonts, they are ~100% compatible. You just use `memoir` with both (or `book` or `article`). `ConTeXt` is a _format_ (like `article`, `memoir`, and "plain" TeX), and would cause significant compatibility issues. You can use Garamond with XeTeX for your own version, then comment out `fontspec` and other font settings, fix any problems from changed line breaks (different font metrics), and you're good to go with pdftex and arxiv.

Comment: @jonalv: yes, I have seen it and love the idea but, at the moment, it still lacks bold, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Mico: I just have linux and windows but it might indeed of interest for others.
@alexis: thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I try to give as many answers as possible:

### Decide if you need it and can use it

As you already know, ArXiv does not accept pdfs created from latex code. So you are out here if you use commercial fonts. Of course you can decide the following:

1. print your articles with the commercial fonts
2. submit the same article with a public fonts to arxiv
3. distribute nice-looking versions from your own web site

This is the route many people are going.

### Select the font

If you will be using latex based on pdftex and not luatex or xetex engines, you need the type1 fonts. That is well documented and clearly explained. In fact, if you don't have more needs it might be even much cheaper to get the fonts in type1 format instead of otf, but I have not experience with that. Of course you can choose to convert otf fonts, but you might come into license hell by this, unless you are a lawyer and can read the small print.

### Check on proper math support

You need to make sure that the font you like has proper math support. Garamond would qualify with a few options. But again, this is up to your decision.

From now on I assume that you have purchased the Adobe Garamond family include Expert Font Set.

### Installing the fonts on Debian

First you have to decide if you install the fonts to TEXMFLOCAL or your home directory. This depends on many factors: multi-user versus single user, backup strategies. My recommendation is for *font packages* to install them into TEXMFLOCAL if it is a single-user system. This makes it much easier wrt to integration into the Debian infrastructure.

Next assume you have received the fonts you have to rename them to proper names. I recommend reading http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt/pad.txt for that. Basically the fonts have to be named:

```
FontName:                   Adobe file name:  TeX file name:
AGaramond-Bold              gdb_____.pfb      padb8a.pfb
AGaramond-BoldItalic        gdbi____.pfb      padbi8a.pfb
AGaramond-Italic            gdi_____.pfb      padri8a.pfb
AGaramond-Regular           gdrg____.pfb      padr8a.pfb
AGaramond-Semibold          gdsb____.pfb      pads8a.pfb
AGaramond-SemiboldItalic    gdsbi___.pfb      padsi8a.pfb
AGaramondExp-Bold           geb_____.pfb      padb8x.pfb
AGaramondExp-BoldItalic     gebi____.pfb      padbi8x.pfb
AGaramondExp-Italic         gei_____.pfb      padri8x.pfb
AGaramondExp-Regular        gerg____.pfb      padr8x.pfb
AGaramondExp-Semibold       gesb____.pfb      pads8x.pfb
AGaramondExp-SemiboldItalic gesbi___.pfb      padsi8x.pfb
```

like this. Then you put the following files into the respective locations:

```
*.pfb   /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/type1/adobe/agaramon/
*.afm   /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/afm/adobe/agaramon/
```

Furthermore, get http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt/pad.zip and unzip it while being *in* `/usr/local/share/texmf`.

After this you have to make the files known to the TeX system by running `mktexlsr /usr/local/share/texmf`.

Finally, you have to activate the fonts. Here it depends on which version of Debian you are using.

### a. Debian squeeze

(currently as of 2012/12 stable, TeX Live 2009)

Add a file `/etc/texmf/updmap.d/00local.cfg` (create if necessary) and add one line:

```
Map pad.map
```

there. After that run `update-updmap` followed by `updmap-sys` (both commands need to be run as root!)

### b. Debian wheezy and above

(as of current testing, but soon stable, TeX Live 2012)

Add/Edit the file `/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` and add above line, then run `updmap-sys` (as root again).

### Using the fonts

You should now be settled with your fonts and simple documents should work. In the following example I am using the Euler math fonts. But that is up to you.

```
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%
% for oldstyle
\usepackage[scaled,osf]{xagaramon}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
```

After this you should be settled with running your documents.

### PostScript: Using MathDesign with URW Garamond

Although you have stated that you do not want to use the URW fonts (where I am not sure why), I suggest to give math-design a try. A simple

```
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

should show you if this is enough for you, especially if you have your theses already in LaTeX format.

To get math-design on Debian/wheezy you have to install `texlive-fonts-extra` by calling `apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` (as root).

### PostScript II: Garamond No8 (garamondx)

If you prefer not to purchase, another option would be the font set garamondx which is not distributed by TeX Live (thus also not Debian), but which is free according to Allading license. They can be used with mathdesign and newtxmath, and might be of interest for you.

How to install on a Debian system: See http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/, but simply get http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts, run it with `texlua install-getnonfreefonts` as root. This will install it into `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/share/texmf`. Then call `getnonfreefonts-sys garamond` and `getnonfreefonts-sys garamondx` (both as root). That should do all the necessary steps on a Debian system with TL2012, too.

If there are any unclear points let me know and I will improve the answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for this very nice answer. I have not tried yet but I have already a naive question. You said: "You need to make sure that the font you like has proper math support. Garamond would qualify with a few options." What do you mean by "with a few options?" and, if you know: how can one tell LaTeX to use a given font for the main text and another one for maths? Thank you again!

Comment: @Alex options *I* know of, but that doesn't mean they are all, are the euler fonts (euler, eulervm, - maybe euler-otf at some point), mathdesign, maybe mtpro2 (commercial), newtxmath. All of them differ in symbols provided. It really depends on what kind of math you are doing and what kind of symbols you need. You cannot get around actually checking the fonts for the symbols you need. As long as you do standard math I guess there are no problems, but special ops or relations are sometimes a problem. Concerning math versus text fonts, that is a complete different story, ... (continued)

Comment: For font selection: with most math fonts you can call the respective package and it will normally only setup the math fonts. By calling a separate package for the text font you set yup both. Example GaramondNo9 with eulervm: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{garamondx} \usepackage{eulervm}`, for Adobe Garamond with eulervm, use: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[osf]{xagaramon} \usepackage{eulervm}`. Some math packages have text font setup included: eg GaramondNo9 or URW with mathdesign: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[garamond,expert]{mathdesign}`. There are many options ...

Answer (score 13):

Here's my attempt to answer your question and the summary is: `don't do it`. Here are the datails:

**Installation**

I've been attempting the same as you did: Converting OTF fonts to use with `pdfLaTeX`. As mentioned in the comments, the way to go forward is to use the [otfinst script](http://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/code/otfinst/). The website gives details and provides a script specifically for Adobe Garamond Pro. As far as I know there should be now difference in using this script under Windows or Linux.

I've used the script to install the font under Windows. The experience was very painful and I would not do it again. In particular, it convinced me to switch to XeLaTeX and/or LuaLaTeX if I have special font needs. This leads me to my second (and more important point):

**Usage**

Here is what I've been through which may help you: For my PhD I am using a modified `classicthesis` and initially used OTF compiling with `XeLaTeX` and I hit [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49502/small-caps-old-style-numbers-and-some-ligatures-produce-odd-symbols-in-pdf-cop). Then I switched to `LuaLaTeX` and hit [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58760/lualatex-fontspec-cannot-compare-documents-with-acrobat). Other things to consider (particularly for `Lua`) is compilation speed if you compile a large(r) document on which you are working regularly. This caused me to go "full circle" and back to `pdfLaTeX´.

This leads to my recommendation: for documents on which you are working on, stick with `pdfLaTeX` and use a nice complete font such as Palatino (`\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}`) or Linux Libertine (`\usepackage[t1]{libertine}`). A commercial and very pretty alternative is Adobe Minion Pro, which is supported through the excellent `MinionPro` package. The package includes a nice font installation guide and the necessary scripts.

Using either of this has an important advantage over going through a (paifull) conversion process with Adobe Garamond Pro: You mention that your thesis is math heavy, and AFAIK there is no perfectly complementary mathfont for Adobe Garamond Pro. This problem does not exist for the fonts I mention above: `mathpazo` has excellent math support and for Libertine and MinionPro you can use the `newtx` package.

Now, for letters, CVs and other documents using OTF with fontspec is probably more suitable (and easier) to use, so you could use Adobe Garamond Pro easily for these kind of files (BTW: given that you are a student, why don't you purchase Photoshop Student edition which [includes](http://techinch.com/blog/fonts-included-with-photoshop-cs6-and-photoshop-elements-10) serveral fonts, including Garamond Pro, Caslon Pro, Minion Pro and others).

I hope this is at least a little helpful for you.

Comment: I am not lawyer, but I always wondered if it is possible to use the trial version of Photoshop or other products that include the Garamond fonts for such a purpose. If you only want to use the fonts for your thesis, it is just very expensive to buy them. So maybe it is legal to download the trial version before you hand in the thesis and use these font files?

Comment: @maetra I'm not going to comment on that. All I'm saying is that the student discount for Photoshop is substantial and you get several (expensive) fonts included with it.

Comment: well I don't think it is good advice to use the Student version since it not allowed to use it for commercial purpose, which in my opinion would be publishing the thesis via some publishing company.

Comment: @maetra I don't see getting the thesis published via a publishing company and using a commercial font being part of this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these very informative remarks; they surely are helpful. Can I ask you to provide a minimal working example with newtx or how to select a font for the main text and another one for maths? By the way, I see on the newtx page that "Ntxmath can also use the maths italic font provided with the garamondx package, thus offering a garamond-alike text-with-maths combination."
Concerning the problem you mention with XeLaTeX, wouldn't this alleviate the problem : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5419/1216 ?

Comment: @Alex Regarding your link: yes it would, but you would *really* loose ligatures, which are an essential part of nice typography.

Comment: @Alex The `garamondx` package does not change much regarding my answer above: `urw-garamond` offers math and text Garamond as well. As the documentation of those packages say, the fonts are based on Adobe *Stempel* Garamond, which is quite different from Adobe Garamond Pro! If you like Stempel, then `urw-garamond`/`garamond` are a really good choice.

Comment: @Jörg: Yes (and it's a pity), but don't I lose them in pdflatex anyway? Or is Libertine (for instance) in pdflatex giving searcheable pdf documents + ligatures?
As for garamondx, I was thinking it could be possible to use Garamond Pro for the main text & that package for the maths.

Comment: @Alex Last comment: I think your request for an MWE for `newtx` should be phrased in a new question, as it is ultimately different from your original question here.

Comment: @Alex No, why would you loose ligatures in `pdfLaTeX`?! And yes, Libertine, MinionPro or other Type1 fonts offer searchable PDFs with `pdfLaTeX` (as does `LuaLaTeX` with OTF). The only problem are smallcaps and ligatures when compiling with `XeLaTeX` using OTFs.

Comment: @Jörg: I was naively thinking pdflatex might either not be compatible with those (as, with the default pdflatex font, there are no ligatures) or give the same problems as XeTeX (which, I thought, was partially due to pdf readers). Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @Alex Computer Modern (the default font) has ligatures. Wikipedia tells us: "TeX is an example of a computer typesetting system that makes use of ligatures automatically. The Computer Modern Roman typeface provided with TeX includes the five common ligatures ff, fi, fl, ffi, and ffl. When TeX finds these combinations in a text it substitutes the appropriate ligature, unless overridden by the typesetter. Opinion is divided over whether it is the job of writers or typesetters to decide where to use ligatures."

Comment: @Jörg: I was actually thinking of a full ligature support, with characters such as  (rather than Th), which Linux Libertine provides automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the [URW Garamond](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond) is not an option? It works (with mathdesign) fine enough for me, I don't know about the arXiv, though.

Comment: URW Garamond is a completely different take on the classical Garamond and hence looks completely different (and in my opinion less good) than Adobe Garamond Pro.

Comment: Well, I'd say "completely different" is a tiny little bit of exaggeration here ... Anyway, the URW type is quite easy to use, so it might just be worth a try.

Comment: You are right, my second "completely different" is an exaggeration :-). I meant it is a "completely different" interpretation of the classical Garamond. As I commented below, URW Garamond and Adobe Stempel Garamond are very similar, but Adobe Garamond Pro is not.

Comment: URW Garamond is also lacking quite a few features. If anything, a fine free (and open-source) replacement for Adobe Garamond is EB Garamond.